# Excel thinks that > is an operator, i want it as a string

Tags: excel

=SUMIFS(L19:L678, J19:J678, ">TEXT", K19:K678, "TEXT")

Is the formula and I want it to look for >TEXT but it thinks I am saying greater than text, how do I get around this?

Comment: Are you sure about that?  Even if it thinks you're saying "smaller than TEXT," it's a greater than operator, not a less than.

Comment: Sorry I mean greater than

Comment: You can include Vlookup formula in the place of >Text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can perhaps use something like that:

```
=SUMIFS(L19:L678, J19:J678, "*>TEXT", K19:K678, "TEXT")
```

Though this will sum if you have `A>TEXT` as well. Otherwise, you might try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((J19:J678=">TEXT")*(K19:K678="TEXT")*(L19:L678))
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this version with an additional "="

`=SUMIFS(L19:L678, J19:J678, "=>TEXT", K19:K678, "TEXT")`

Comment: +1 Hmm, that the first good reason I see to use the equal sign in the criteria of a `SUMIF`(s).